# Find process by port

Tags: shell, centos

I've been trying to list PID's that are older then 8 minutes on a specific port.

```
for each in $(find /proc -maxdepth 1 -user root -mmin +8 -exec basename {} \;); do echo $each; done
```

My current code will dump all processes older than 8 minutes but I can't find any documentation regarding port flags in find. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I approached the issue from a different direction and came up with the following:

```
for i in $(pgrep -f "server.php"); do
    pidtime=$(stat -c '%Y' /proc/$i)
    now=$(date +%s)
    ((now - pidtime >= 6)) && {
      kill $i;
      sleep 1;
      kill &>/dev/null -9 $i;
    }
done
```